# Clean easy way to expand window according to subviews

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, master-detail

I'm developing an application that uses a master-detail paradigm with an `NSTableView` as the master and an `NSView` as the detail. The `NSView` gets populated from another `NSViewController's` view; I have an individual `NSViewController` for each of the detail views and their views are configured in XIBs. What's the cleanest way to have the main window expand only as necessary (preferably with animation) to fit the current detail view (similar to what System Preferences does)? Sorry if this is an elementary question; I'm rather new at desktop Cocoa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the size of the window you need to accommodate your master and selected detail view. You can get the size of your detail view:

```
NSSize detailViewFrameSize = [[detailViewController view] frame].size;
```

Resize the window:

```
[window setFrame:frameRect display:YES animate:YES];
```

Add the detail subview to the specified position.

```
[[window contentView] addSubview:detailView];
```